# Solrnet : modify default Operator

Tags: solr, operators, solrnet

I use solrnet and I would add an "advanced search" on my website. For this, i need to change default operator ("OR" or "AND")

I try this with

```
this.solr.Query(new LocalParams {{"q.op", "OR"}} + q, options);
```

However, the query generated is between quote and it's for exact query (I query solr with "SolrQueryByField").

So, is it possible to query solr and change the default operator or remove quote at request.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know SolrNet, but you can modify the default operator of your `solrQueryParser` in your server http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml maybe that's can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SolrQuery` instead of `SolrQueryByField`. `SolrQuery` is pass-through, anything you give it is passed as-is to Solr (modulo URL encoding of course)